# Get Get timeslots based on given data and time each 15 min jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with timeslots based on given data and time, and i have issues.

I have **start time** **15:00**, and **endtime** **00:15**, ad with my method i recived error.

```
function parseTime(s) {
  var c = s.split(':');
  return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
}

function convertHours(mins){
  var hour = Math.floor(mins/60);
  var mins = mins%60;
  var converted = pad(hour, 2)+':'+pad(mins, 2);
  return converted;
}

function pad(str, max) {
    str = str.toString();
    return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}

function calculatTimeSlot(startTime, endTime, interval = "15") {
    var i, formattedTime;
    var timeSlots = new Array();
    for (var i = startTime; i <= endTime; i = i + interval) {
            formattedTime = convertHours(i);
            timeSlots.push(formattedTime);
        }
    return timeSlots;
}



var startTime = parseTime("15:00"),
    endTime = parseTime("00:15"),
interval = 15;   
var timesAray = calculatTimeSlot(startTime, endTime, interval);

console.log(timesAray);
```

In the output i have empty array, but i want to get:

```
["15:00", "15:15", "15:30", "15:45"...."00:00", "00:15"]
```

How i can fix this?

Comment: Looks like you did not close the `calculateTimeSlot` function, or was it just wrongly copied over? I also don't see a return of the `timeSlots` array.

Comment: @MaartenPeels i fix code

Comment: `parseTime("00:15")` results in 15, so it will never enter the loop.

Comment: @MaartenPeels and this is a problem

Comment: You're trying to get intervals that span on 2 days but your code doesn't have any concept of days, it can only handle hours and minutes.

Comment: @Titus any idea how to fix it :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this by using `Date` objects. Here is an example:

```js
function getDateWithTime(time) {
  var date = new Date();
  var timeArr = time.split(":").map(v => parseInt(v));
  date.setHours(timeArr[0]);
  date.setMinutes(timeArr[1]);
  return date;
}

function getIntervals(start, end, interval = 15) {
  var intervals = [];
  while (start <= end) {
    var h = start.getHours();
    var m = start.getMinutes();
    h = String(h).padStart(2, "0");
    m = String(m).padStart(2, "0");
    intervals.push(`${h}:${m}`);
    start.setMinutes(start.getMinutes() + interval);
  }
  return intervals;
}

var startTime = "15:00";
var endTime = "00:15";

var start = getDateWithTime(startTime);
var end = getDateWithTime(endTime);

if (end < start) { // deal with cases when the intervals span on 2 days
  end.setDate(end.getDate() + 1);
}

console.log(getIntervals(start, end, 15));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `endTime` is "00:15" the `parseTime` function will return 15, because of this the loop will never run.

A dirty fix would be:

```
function parseTime(s) {
  var c = s.split(':');
  if (c[0] === "00") c[0] = "24";
  return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
}
```

Then the code will return:
`["15:00", "15:15", "15:30", "15:45", "16:00", "16:15", "16:30", "16:45", "17:00", "17:15", "17:30", "17:45", "18:00", "18:15", "18:30", "18:45", "19:00", "19:15", "19:30", "19:45", "20:00", "20:15", "20:30", "20:45", "21:00", "21:15", "21:30", "21:45", "22:00", "22:15", "22:30", "22:45", "23:00", "23:15", "23:30", "23:45", "24:00", "24:15"]`

You would have to rewrite your `convertHours` as well because it shows `24:00` instead of `00:00`

Again: this is not the best solution, as @Titus said best would be to add the concept of days.

Comment: Some how can i have in the end not **24:00, but 00:00**

Comment: @Andrew You can use `var hour = Math.floor(mins/60) % 24` in the `convertHours` function.

Comment: But in case if i will put start time "00:15", end time "05:45" and code not working